# How to make viewModelScope wait for a suspend function in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As we know the default dispatcher for viewModelScope executes in parallel. How do I make viewModelScope wait for the suspend function in unit test . In my code i would like to get the result from `repository.getData()` so that my assertion passes. Right now, i don't get the result on time.

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository: Repository,
                     private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcherProvider) : ViewModel() {

    private val viewState = MutableLiveData<Results<Data>>()
    fun getViewState() : LiveData<Results<Data>> = viewState



    fun getData(query: search) {
        viewState.value = Loading
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher.main()) {
            val results = repository.getData(query) //need to wait for this
            when(results){
                    is Success -> {
                        viewState.value = Success(results.data)
                    }
                    is Error -> viewState.value = Error(“Error”)
                }
        }
```

MainViewModelTest:

```
 Class MainViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()


    @Test
    fun `test get data`() = coroutineTestRule.testCoroutineDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        coEvery{repository.getData(“query”)} returns Success(Data)

        var observer:Observer<Results<Data>> = mock()

        viewModel.getViewState().observeForever(observer)

        viewModel.getData(“query”)

          assertEquals(Loading, state)
          assertEquals(resultSuccess, state)

       }

    }
```

Comment: "As we know viewModelScope executes in parallel" -- what happens in parallel is determined by the dispatcher, not the `CoroutineScope`. The default dispatcher for `viewModelScope` is `Dispatchers.Main`, which has a single thread (Android's main application thread).

Comment: Beyond that, I use [this `MainDispatcherRule`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v1.0/T36-Internet/ToDo/app/src/test/java/com/commonsware/todo/MainDispatcherRule.kt) to allow me to control when coroutines for `Dispatchers.Main` get executed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the response, Yes, sorry i didn't word it correctly. i have edited it. Should i also add the MainDispatcherRule class to my test along with CoroutineTestRule?. As the CoroutineTestRule is somehow similar. How would i use this MainDispatcherRule to solve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand what you were aiming for. I think your test is not created correctly. I often use https://github.com/jraska/livedata-testing and the `TestObserver` that it offers, which would replace your `observer` and allow you to assert the results of the observation when it occurs. IOW, you don't want to to block `getData()`; you want to block the assertion.

Comment: I am observing a similar issue with `viewModelScope` functions launched in the ViewModel from a unit test. According to [Craig Russell's](https://twitter.com/trionkidnapper) [post here](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/), the solution seems to be to inject the CoroutineScope into the ViewModel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coroutines - unit testing viewModelScope.launch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765190/coroutines-unit-testing-viewmodelscope-launch-methods)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `observer.onChanged()` for assertions and verifications. I don't see a problem otherwise.

```
val successResult = Result.Success(Data)
coEvery{repository.getData(“query”)} returns successResult

verify { observer.onChanged(Result.Loading) }
verify { observer.onChanged(successResult) }
```